# Как менять строку из класса Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим я создал игру квест. У меня есть класс героя, код:

```
class Hero:
def __init__(self, name, hp, loot):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = hp
    self.loot = loot
```

Как увидим у него есть аргумент "loot", так вот, допустим, я спросил у игрока, что сделать с вещами в инвентаре? Он выбирает - удалить, и как мне удалить эту строку?
Еще подробнее: в "loot" есть строка "Спички, скрепка, копейка" он выбирает - выбросить спички
И как мне их удалить из "инвентаря"?
Мой вопрос о том: как удалить что-либо из строки которая находится в классе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Довольно плохая идея для хранения коллекции элементов использовать строки.
Множества (ну или списки) - вот, что поможет Вам, и из коробки предоставит функционал, который Вы желаете.

***Пример:***

```py
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, loot):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.loot = loot

unit = Hero('nomnoms12', 1337, {'Спички', 'скрепка', 'копейка'})

print("Инвентарь:", unit.loot)

unit.loot.discard('копейка')
print('копейка удалена из инвентаря')

print("Инвентарь:", unit.loot)
```

*stdout:*

```
Инвентарь: {'копейка', 'скрепка', 'Спички'}
копейка удалена из инвентаря
Инвентарь: {'скрепка', 'Спички'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете присвоить какое либо условное значение, которое будет означать отсутствие предмета. Далее проверяйте наличие предмета, как неравенство этому значению. В качестве значения, обозначающего отсутствие предмета, в Python можно использовать специальный объект `None`

```py
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, loot):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.loot = loot

    def remove_loot():
        self.loot = None

    def loot_exists():
        return self.loot is not None
```